Chern class of roots of the canonical bundle
How can one compute the Chern class of line bundles that are roots of the canonical bundle? For example the theta characteristic is K^{1/2} and in general we can have line bundles that look like K^{m/n} such that m, n are integers. I need the Chern class of these bundles in terms of the Chern class of the canonical bundle.

In general you have $c_1(L^{\otimes n}) = n c_1(L)$, because $c_1$ is a group homomorphism $c_1: \operatorname{Pic}(X) \to H^2(X,\mathbb Z)$. So if $L^{\otimes 2} = K$, then $c_1(L) = \frac 1 2 c_1(K)$.

You have to be careful with the expression $\frac{1}{2}c_1(K)$. In general, if $\alpha = 2\beta$ in $H^2(X; \mathbb{Z})$, there could be another element $\beta' \in H^2(X; \mathbb{Z})$ with $\alpha = 2\beta'$, in which case, it's not clear which class $\frac{1}{2}\alpha$ refers to ($\beta$ or $\beta'$)? This issue only occurs if $H^2(X; \mathbb{Z})$ has $2$-torsion as $2(\beta' - \beta) = 0$.
